# How can I clear drawimage?

Tags: vb.net, drawing

[image]

In order to make my image transparent, I used:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    myGraphics.DrawImage(Img1, 500, 190)
End Sub
```

My problem now how can I erase `myGraphics.DrawImage(Img1, 500, 190)`
or replace it with another image?

Comment: thanks for editing @adrianbanks

Comment: Is this done in a form? The reason I ask is because usually this is done with the paint events and not on clicking a button...

Comment: yes in forms. i have made my solutions tho. i inserted image using code in a picturebox and the image became transparent as long as the picture box is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I erase `myGraphics.DrawImage(Img1, 500, 190)` or replace it with another image?

A little information (***boring stuff***) to help you understand how `Graphics.DrawImage` works and what you can do to clear/remove/delete and all the above.

When you use the `Graphics.DrawImage` it is ***permanent*** as it is utilizing the `Graphics` class in which it uses GDI to draw the image. Once this happens you no longer have access to that drawn object ***unless***... you keep a copy of it. Also it is important that you should be doing the drawing in the `Paint Events` and not the latter. This keeps drawing resources down and also give's you access to the `Graphics` object instead of creating one yourself.

**Here is the solution...**

```
'Used to keep current graphics object so you can use it later...
Private gObject As System.Drawing.Graphics = Nothing

 'Create the image...
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    myGraphics.DrawImage(Img1, 500, 50)

    'Clear this out if we can and should...
    If Me.gObject IsNot Nothing Then Me.gObject.Clear(Me.BackColor)

    'Save the Graphics object...
    Me.gObject = myGraphics

End Sub
```

That take's care of creating the image and clearing it out every time you click that button. As for replacing that image, you don't show how you would populate them. The code is the same though; clear the object and reset it and then save the new copy to the variable...